# Items in package explorer are white and do not group in folders

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project in Eclipse that somehow does not group the 'res' or 'bin' items in the package explorer into groups but shows them as individual items with 'white' folder icons.
The image shows this. In the 'Countdown' project you have res.layout, res.menu etc. but in the NewProject these are both in the 'res' folder.
The CountDown project also refuses to build with the error 'R cannot be resolved to variable'. I know this is due to the fact that the R.java file is not created by the pre-compiler and I assume this is also related to the fact that the folder structure looks different.
Now I have already tried many things like cleaning the project and rebuild manually but so far nothing solves this problem.

[image: Eclipse package explore with colored an white entries]

Comment: set up your project buid path

Comment: Check the naming of your resources and follow the rule of using only [a-z0-9._] for the naming

Comment: I've checked the build path and the naming of the resources. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your project settings: right click the project -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> Tab `Source`. Compare these settings with the other project.

Comment: That solved it. In the build path->Source that was an extra entry for 'Countdown' that included 'All'. Just removed that and now the folder structure is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have directly import a project into eclipse and you are on Linux System. As Linux has its own security, i suggest you to find `.class` & `.project` files in your project folder ( which are hidden, so use CTRL + H to view ). Now right click on these files and change its permission.  Come back to Eclipse, refresh the project and clean. That's it.

Comment: Nope. I'm on a Windows 8 system. And CTRL-H does nothing by the way.